# React Native - Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-secure-key-store:

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build-type

I am trying to install the package 'react-native-secure-key-store' and run it on Android. i have the following error during the build

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-secure-key-store

```
    * What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-secure-key-store.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-secure-key-store: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

I installed the package manually and here are the files.

MainApplication.java

```
package com.retailnativeapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.babisoft.ReactNativeLocalization.ReactNativeLocalizationPackage;
import io.realm.react.RealmReactPackage; 
import com.oblador.keychain.KeychainPackage;
import com.reactlibrary.securekeystore.RNSecureKeyStorePackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG; 
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new ReactNativeLocalizationPackage(),
            new RealmReactPackage(),
            new KeychainPackage(),
            new RNSecureKeyStorePackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-secure-key-store'
project(':react-native-secure-key-store').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-secure-key-store/android')
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.retailnativeapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-localization')
    compile project(':realm')
    compile project(':react-native-keychain')
    compile project(':react-native-secure-key-store')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

can you suggest what can I do to fix this please.

Thank you for your help.
R

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I also have this. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I am seeing it on latest react native version . Did you find a solution ?